# Python - How can I make this repetitive code shorter by using loop?

Tags: python, scipy, chi-squared

I'm very new to Python.
This following is an example of my data:

```
Category    May  June  July
Product1    32   41    43
Product2    74   65    65
Product3    17   15    18
Product4    14   13    14
```

I have many sets of data and I'd like to calculate Chi-square for each set.
The code is as follow:

```
Product1 = [32,41,43]
chi2, p = scipy.stats.chisquare(Product1)
print('Product1')
if p > 0.05:
    print('Same')
else:
    print('Different')

Product2 = [74,65,65]
chi2, p = scipy.stats.chisquare(Product2)
print('Product2')
if p > 0.05:
    print('Same')
else:
    print('Different')

Product3 = [17,15,18]
chi2, p = scipy.stats.chisquare(Product3)
print('Product3')
if p > 0.05:
    print('Same')
else:
    print('Different')

Product4 = [14,13,14]
chi2, p = scipy.stats.chisquare(Product4)
print('Prokduct4')
if p > 0.05:
    print('Same')
else:
    print('Different')
```

I used "df = pd.read_excel" to insert the data table and it comes with index and I don't know how to call each row to calculate.

How can I make this repetitive code shorter by using loop and pull the data from the table?
  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Is your data a two dimensional list(array)? how do you handle your data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *could* use a loop to repeat the steps above, but you might as well leverage `scipy`'s ability to deal with `pandas` dataframes! You can apply the [`chisquare`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html) test over all rows of a dataframe using `axis=1`. For exmample:

```
from scipy.stats import chisquare

df['p'] = chisquare(df[['May', 'June', 'July']], axis=1)[1]

df['same_diff'] = np.where(df['p'] > 0.05, 'same', 'different')

>>> df
   Category  May  June  July         p same_diff
0  Product1   32    41    43  0.411506      same
1  Product2   74    65    65  0.672294      same
2  Product3   17    15    18  0.869358      same
3  Product4   14    13    14  0.975905      same
```

Now your dataframe has your `p` values as a column, and whether they are "same" or "different" as a column

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I'm looking for.
I really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

I will start after the data is loaded into pandas data frame:

[image]

Then, you can do:

```
for row in df.iterrows():
    product = row[1][0]
    chi, p = scipy.stats.chisquare(row[1][1:])
    print(product, ":", "same" if p > 0.05 else "different")
```

This will print:

```
Product1 : same
Product2 : same
Product3 : same
Product4 : same
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I really appreciate it.